# nVidia: Converting Windows color settings to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, colors, nvidia-settings

Under windows, I have my monitor's color settings set to the following, via the nVidia control panel:

- Brightness: +60%
- Contrast: +60%
- Gamma: +1.00

When I boot up from Linux, however the settings for Brightness, Contrast, and Gamma are not measured or represented the same way.  Instead of being percentile, they are floating point multipliers.  Presumably, one would set Brightness and Contrast to 0.6 to be equivalent to +60%, but that is not the case, and instead I get far more extreme results.

How would I convert the values from the Windows to something usable on the nVidia control panel in Linux?

Please show me the math, as I have a second monitor which requires different settings.